# Aws serverless services to redirect browser http requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, redirect, load-balancing

I was given a very simple task of redirecting multiple existing domains to a new single domain with 301 status code response. Now I have started thinking, that is there some simple way to achieve this kind of browser redirection without involving a virtual machine in AWS? I'm looking to implement something like the following that I can do with nginx configuration:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name some.domain.xyz;
 return 301 https://some.other.com/yadayada/231312;

}
```

Can this kind of behaviour be implemented in aws without needing to host a full http server? Using some trickery with a load balancer perhaps (I have never used these before)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official documentation for [accomplishing this with an AWS Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/).

You can also do this with S3, [as described here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/).

Comment: The problem with the S3 method is that it does not support https with custom domain names. I'll check that ALB way next.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to add CloudFront to the mix to handle https with S3. I think the Application Load Balancer method may be the cleanest/easiest solution.

Comment: Now I'm struggling to get the load balancer to be accessible from the internet. I'm using the default vpc, and I added security policy to allow http and https from any source, but I cannot connect to it with curl using the dns name listed in the load balancer description. Should I be able to access this internet facing load balancer from there?

Comment: Yes, the security group for the load balancer should allow all traffic on ports 80 and 443, and then you should be able to hit it at the load balancer's DNS name. Are you getting a network timeout error?

Comment: Yes, connection timed out.

Comment: Are you sure the security group you are looking at is actually attached to the load balancer?

Comment: Yes I had an improper security group attached to the alb, now everything works as intended!